Does the nuclear human exosome contain 9 or 11 subunits?
I'm currently reading about the nuclear human exosome, in particular, looking at the protein complex that was uploaded here; https://www.rcsb.org/3d-view/2NN6
According to the paper related to it, it mentions that: "The hExo9 structure reveals locations for each of the nine polypeptides in the complex (Figure 2). Human Rrp41, hRrp45, hRrp46, hRrp43, hMtr3, and hRrp42 form a PH-domain ring, akin to that observed for PNPase, RNase PH, and the archaeal exosome (Figure 3)."
However, the figures in the paper don't really show RRP44 and RRP6 but the supplementary shows 11 results under H. sapiens: https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0092867406014279-mmc2.pdf
I'm just a bit confused, does the human exosome complex consist of nine or eleven subunits? And in terms of terminology, does each polypeptide chain equal to one chain as mentioned in the global stoichiometry?

Quotes from the paper:

While Rrp44 is an integral component of the yeast exosome, human Rrp44 (Dis3) is not present in human exosome preparations (Allmang et al., 1999, Raijmakers et al., 2004).

So there is a human analog of Rrp44 which is part of the yeast exosome but not the human exosome.

Rrp6 is associated with nuclear exosomes in yeast and human, although Rrp6 may not be restricted to the nucleus (Graham et al., 2006).

They say Rrp6 is associated with human exosomes, but do not state that it is a component of them.

The emerging consensus is that eukaryotic exosomes also form six-subunit PH-domain rings (Rrp41, Rrp45, Rrp46, Rrp42, Rrp43, and Mtr3) that are capped by S1 proteins (Csl4, Rrp4, and Rrp40). It has been suggested that Rrp44 and Rrp6 interact with the “bottom” of the PH-ring, surfaces opposite to those that interact with Csl4, Rrp4, and Rrp40 (Hernandez et al., 2006).


We next attempted to assemble yeast and human nine-subunit exosomes (yExo9 or hExo9). Human Csl4, hRrp4, and hRrp40 were mixed with hRrp41/Rrp45, hRrp46, and hRrp43/Mtr3/Rrp42 as above. Consistent with formation of a nine-protein complex, the apparent molecular weight (∼350 kDa) was consistent with the predicted mass, and SDS-PAGE analysis confirmed that peak fractions contained each of the nine proteins (Figure 1C)

Here they describe the nine-subunit human exosome that they build and list all the constituent parts.

The hExo9 structure reveals locations for each of the nine polypeptides in the complex

Again, clear they are talking about a 9 subunit complex.
I think overall it's probably of only moderate biological interest how many of these subunits make up the "complex" proper, if the other proteins are also there and interacting, it's just a matter of which "stick together" through the methodology being applied. Perhaps a bit analogous to the "lumpers and splitters" phenomenon in categorization, cellular and molecular biologists can choose to be more or less reductive in how they analyze protein function. Even the most solitary proteins interact with others, and at different levels of analysis it may make more or less sense to group subunits together into a complex or treat them as separate units with distinct activity.

wouldn't the components matter though? but if I'm comparing the ground truth against an AlphaFold-multimer prediction using the 11 associated proteins, then the prediction wouldn't be correct since two extra proteins have been included?

@Strider Depends what you're doing. Seems like you'd just want the 9 for what you want but it's quite possible the other two also interact and bind, just not tight enough to stay together.

I want to compare ground truth vs the predicted exosome. Do you think its because only the 9 subunits could only be crystallised?

I don't know, maybe you'll find out when you do your experiment! It's no fun to do an experiment when you already know the results.
